# Ansible set multiple ports in sshd_config

Tags: ansible, port, sshd

i am using a base role to configure several aspects of servers, one of them is the ssh_config.

For a special server I now need to listen with sshd to 2 ports.

However, the sshd_config defines to add multiple ports by adding a new Line Ports with the port number like this:

```
Port 22
Port 2022
```

Because the key is the same, I assume to have problems with the lineinfile module which I am currently using. Any ideas how to solve this?

UPDATE:
I tried and it is not working. Instead Port 22 is set first and than removed and Port 2022 is set.

Here is my ansible task:

```
- name: server individuell SSH configuration if set
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
    line: "{{ item.name }} {{ item.value }}"
    regexp: "^{{ item.name }} "
 with_items: "{{ ssh_config_advanced }}"
notify: restart SSHD
tags: ssh_config
```

and the dictionary:

```
ssh_config_advanced: 
  - { "name": "Port", "value": "22" }
  - { "name": "Port", "value": "7122" }
```

Comment: `Because the key is the same, I assume to have problems with the lineinfile module which I am currently using`. Don't assume: try it, see if you effectively get a problem, try to solve it and ask a question with a [mre] specifying the very exact problem you are then trying to solve. Hint: line in file can perfectly be used to check the presence of 2 different lines starting with `Port` followed by different ports and the absence of any other line starting with `Port` but not followed by a known port.

Comment: No it is not working. I tried having both port configs in a dictionary and ansible is than setting Port 22 first and than removing Port 22 and adding Port 2022.
Interesting also that the previous setting of Port 22 with a # before was ignored.

Comment: I updated my initial questions for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your regexp making `lineinfile` replace any line starting with `"Port"`. Simply dropping the `regexp:` stanza in your above code would already achieve your requirement in most situations.

But if you want to make sure that only the required ports are left in the file (in case you change one of them for example) the following example will make the job in an idempotent fashion.

I'll give you the overall idea with a simple playbook. You can later put this back into your more complicated data structure for your config if you wish to.

*Note: if you intend to describe many sshd setting in a complex data structure, this is usually a warning sign you should stop using `lineinfile` and switch to a template.*

Given the following initial `sshd_config` test file

```
Setting a
Setting b
Port 67
Setting c
```

the following playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    ssh_ports:
      - 22
      - 34

    sshd_config_file: sshd_config

  tasks:
    - name: Make sur no line with unwanted ports are left
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        regexp: ^Port (?!{{ ssh_ports | map('regex_escape') | join('|') }}).*$
        state: absent
        path: "{{ sshd_config_file }}"

    - name: Add needed ports to config
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        line: 'Port {{ item }}'
        state: present
        path: "{{ sshd_config_file }}"
      loop: "{{ ssh_ports }}"
```

gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Make sur no line with unwanted ports are left] ***************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Add needed ports to config] **********************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=22)
changed: [localhost] => (item=34)

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

and the new file content is:

```
Setting a
Setting b
Setting c
Port 22
Port 34
```

Comment: thanks. So the solution is to remove all entries first and than set the entries which are defined? Indeed it might be better to go for a template approach. But thanks anyway for the good solution proposal

Comment: The important point to note here is that the above solution first remove entries **only if they do not contain a desired port** and add lines **only if they do not exist**. In other words, it is  fully idempotent and will not change anything on any subsequent run after the first one if you do not change your port values and your file wasn't modified by any other external method..